# Python Selenium for getting the whole content of table in Reactjs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape the content of table from wyscout.com, which seems that is built by Reacjs.
After log in, script selects the country(e.g. England), League(e.g. Premier League), Team(e.g. Arsenal). Here choose Stats tab.
Then, it shows the table to scrape the data. Even if there is a button to export a excel file, I want to scrape the content manually using selenium or beautifulsoup.
However, script gets only 18 rows even though the number of rows on the table is more than 100.
Please let me know the solution.
Thanks.

Here is my code.

```py
from re import search
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import string
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Load Chrome Browser
show_browser = True

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')

scraped_data = []

def bot_driver(url, user_name, user_password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    time.sleep(2)

    # Log in
    # login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='avia-menu']/li[5]/a")
    # login.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    idd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_username']")
    idd.send_keys(user_name)
    passW = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_password']")
    passW.send_keys(user_password)
    time.sleep(2)

    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='login_button']")
    submit.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    try:
        force_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn2_zFM sc-jDwBTQ cUKaFo -block3u2Qh -primary1dLZk']")
        force_login.click()
        print('force loging')
    except :
        print('force login error')

    return driver

def select_country(driver, country_name):
    # Specific Country
    # country = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@commandsource='list@area_list@30']")))
    # country = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@commandsource='list@area_list@30']")
    
    # All the countries
    list_country = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='detail_0_home_navy']/div[1]/div/div")))
    time.sleep(3)
    for entry in list_country:
        if country_name == entry.text:
            print('country click here')
            entry.click()
            return driver, 1
    
    return driver, 0

def select_league(driver, league_name):
    # Specific League
    # league = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@commandsource='list@competition_list@0']")
    
    # All the leagues
    list_league = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='detail_0_area_navy_0']/div[1]/div/div")
    for entry in list_league:
        if league_name == entry.text:
            entry.click()
            return driver, 1
    
    return driver, 0

def select_team(driver, team_names):
    # Specific Team
    # team = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@commandsource='list@team_list@0']")

    flag_team = 0
    list_team = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='detail_0_competition_navy_0']/div[1]/div/div")
    for entry in list_team:
        if entry.text in team_names:
            flag_team = 1
            print('selected team = ', entry.text)
            entry.click()
            time.sleep(2)

            # Stats
            stats = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Stats')))
            stats.click()
            time.sleep(3)
                        
            WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='detail_0_team_stats']/div/div/div/main/div[3]/div[2]/div/table")))
            content_stats = driver.page_source
            soup_stats = BeautifulSoup(content_stats, "html.parser")

            table_stats = soup_stats.find('table', attrs={'class': 'teamstats__Index-module__table___1K93L teamstats__Index-module__with-opp___16Rp5'})
            # print(table_stats)
            tbody_stats = table_stats.find('tbody')
            tr_stats = tbody_stats.find_all('tr')
            print('number of tr = ', len(tr_stats))


            # Return to team selection
            back_team = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='detail_0_team_back']")))
            back_team.click()
            time.sleep(5)
    
    if flag_team == 1:
        return driver, 1
    else:
        return driver, 0



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # User input

    # Login - wyscout_url = 'https://wyscout.com/'
    wyscout_url = 'https://platform.wyscout.com/app/?/'
    wyscout_user_name = '' # username
    wyscout_user_password = '' # password
    wyscout_driver = bot_driver(wyscout_url, wyscout_user_name, wyscout_user_password)
    time.sleep(10)

    # Select a Country
    country = 'England' # .upper()
    wyscout_driver, succeed = select_country(wyscout_driver, country)
    if succeed == 0:
        print('NO country!')
    time.sleep(7)

    # Select a league
    league = 'Premier League' # .upper()
    wyscout_driver, succeed = select_league(wyscout_driver, league)
    if succeed == 0:
        print('NO League!')
    time.sleep(7)

    # Select team
    team_options = ['Arsenal']
    wyscout_driver, succeed = select_team(wyscout_driver, team_options)
    time.sleep(7)
    if succeed == 0:
        print('NO Team!')
    time.sleep(7)


    print('!!!Wyscout END!!!')
    # wyscout_driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please share your code here

Comment: Hi, Sir I shared my code. Please give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but this website asks for a login. Sorry for being blunt, but it's hard to register to check queries like this one, as there would be multiple queries everyday and to keep registering for every website is not good for the solution provider. Having said that, I tried registering nevertheless, but it asks for a payment even though I selected a free trial. So, sorry but it's hard to help in such a situation.
One suggestion I could give is: Try to check if you can find a parent element of where you are erring out, and try to traverse from it. React websites are challenging to work with

Answer (score 3):

Finally I figured it out by myself.
Here is my solution.

```py
            # Scroll down
            print('scroll down')
            last_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", table_stats)            
            time.sleep(3)

            while True:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)", table_stats)
                time.sleep(5)

                new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", table_stats)               

                if new_height == last_height:
                    break
                    
                last_height = new_height

            print('scroll end')
```